# Как сделать закрытие блока при клике вне его границ?

Tags: javascript

Приветствую.

Есть код, который открывает небольшой функциональный блок.

Код:

```
$('.rememberadd').bind('click', function () {

    // Получаем ID блока, который нужно показать
    var title = $(this).data("target");

    // Показываем блок
    $(this).after($(title));
    $(title).slideDown(500);


});

// При уходе мышки со ссылки
$('.close').bind('click', function () {

    // Получаем ID блока, который нужно показать
// Скрываем блок
    $('#rememberblock').slideUp(500);

});
```

Как сделать, чтобы блок скрывался при клике вне его области?

Answer (score 1):

Отлавливай клики по body и назначай блоку display:none;

Comment: Вариант хороший, но не то немного. Нашел уже решение.